# Is there a way to create associations in SPD 2013 with two foreign keys related to the same table

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have two tables: the first one is Person and the second one is Project. Project has two foreign keys related to Person, as "manager" and "second project responsible". I created two external content types and then I made the first association with manager and Person id, but making the second one to link "second project responsible" has encountered an error.

As I read on these links below,

[Adding Associations Between External Content Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394528(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_2)

[Creating SharePoint Server 2010 External Content Type Associations with SharePoint Designer 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728816.aspx#Anchor_2)

there are limitations on associations building in SPD 2010. Solutions provided aren't compliant with my purposes, because I can't use visual studio and I need a way to preserve the references constraints on my DB, without altering them. Is there a way to achieve this in SPD 2013?